# Conditional Trial Expiry in Django App

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to create a template-driven expiring trial for an app and I'm not sure why my current method isn't working.

When a user signs up, I create a new customer and current_subscription with plan named "free trial":

```
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def create_trial(sender, **kwargs):

    user = kwargs['user']
    customer = Customer.create(user)

    fn = settings.TRIAL_PERIOD_FOR_USER_CALLBACK
    days = fn(user)
    start = datetime.now()
    end = start + timedelta(days=days)
    sub = CurrentSubscription.objects.create(customer=customer,
                                             plan="free trial",
                                             quantity="1",
                                             status='trialing',
                                             trial_start=start,
                                             trial_end=end,
                                             start=start,
                                             current_period_end=end,
                                             amount=0)
```

[image]

then I have a conditional template tag targeting user's plan to bring up a menu telling the user their trial has expired instead of the app:

```
{% if not current_subscription.plan == 'free trial' or current_subscription.is_valid %}
# trial expiry stuff
{% endif %}
```

but even when the trial's expired and plan's value != 'free trial' in db my conditional isn't evaluating correctly. Is my tag wrong? thanks

Comment: what about `{% if current_subscription.plan != 'free trial' or  not current_subscription.is_valid %}`

Answer (score 1):

The condition you evaluate is incorrect, probably because you suppose `not` is applied to your two conditions. (while it is just applied to the boolean test that directly follows it)

You could also have some problem with the `is_valid` method. (post its code so we can check that out)

Here's the correct conditional statement:

```
{% if current_subscription.plan != 'free trial' or not current_subscription.is_valid %}
# trial expiry stuff
{% endif %}
```

That should work better.

Comment: yep thought 'not' applied to both conditions, thanks for clarifying that and pointing out my errors. however, is_valid() is throwing "Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'current_subscription.is_valid()'"

Comment: Oups, my fault, in Django it seems like you don't put parenthesis in method calls ! Gonna fix that.

Could you give us the code of your ``is_valid`` method ? ; Also, could you test this with a plan that is not 'free trial'? Because if even that doesn't work, it means your subscriptions are all 'free trial'.